# Error: Failed to collect page data for /dashboard

Tags: node.js, next.js, build, npm-build

I use nextjs to build the frontend of my website. I recently added some code (which I'm pretty sure is correct) to my project.

After running `npm run build`, I got an error that tells me that nextjs failed to collect the data for one of my pages.

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /dashboard
    at C:\Users\ga_bo\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:916:15 {
  type: 'Error'
}
```

I recently upgraded the version of node I use from version 16 to version 18. I thought this caused the error, so I deleted the local repository of my project and reinstalled version 16 of node then reclone my project repo and then run `npm run build`, but the error still occure.

I even tried removing the changes I made to the code and running `npm run build`, but the error still occurs!!!

I am really confused about this error, please help me if you have any idea what is causing it.

Comment: Is the error provided the complete stack trace from Node?

Comment: Yes, here is the error stack trace :
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1160:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)

Comment: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ga_bo\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\react-countup\build\index.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:14)

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error when my `getStaticPaths` method was trying to fetch JSON from localhost, but I forgot to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to a new update to the library you're using, react-countup. As mentioned by rhammel-aip on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/glennreyes/react-countup/issues/805#issuecomment-1530117233), you can put this into your package.json for now to fix this issue:

```
"resolutions": {
    "react-countup/countup.js": "2.5.0"
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, this didn't work for me, but I found some useful information that helps me in the link you gave me